# "There are no more endpoints available from the Endpoint Mapper" exception when pinging

Tags: c#, azure, ping

I have a very small website running on Azure in the shared hosting configuration. I have a bunch of networking code on it that involves opening sockets, all of which works successfully.

I have written some code that sends a ping and I get a `PingException` being thrown, with the inner exception being a `Win32Exception` with the description

```
There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper
```

I am making a guess that it's because I'm trying to send an ICMP request, but any guidance would be appreciated, and particularly a work around.

Comment: You're fair thrashing the network stack right? If I understand correctly, you've used up all your ephemeral ports and caused port-exhaustion (i.e. ports that are opened to receive a reply from the network). If you're feeling brave, reduce the TIME_WAIT of your network equipment (a bad idea)... otherwise, slow down or get a second IP address..

Comment: @spender Nope, I'm not thrashing the network at all. Honestly! This happens even when nothing else is happening on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am seeing the same errors. I believe this is happening because many Azure services, including Web Apps, do not allow outbound ICMP:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/71c85bea-572a-4232-87f8-3e45e674f08a/there-are-no-more-endpoints-available-on-azure-website?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview